# Using a Java interface with a recursive type from Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am using a library with an interface for a Builder that looks like this:

```
public interface LibInterface<L extends LibInterface> {
    L method();
}
```

When trying to use it from scala:

```
val b = instanceOfLibInterface.method()
```

The type of b ends up being `Any`, instead of something like `LibInterface[_ :> LibInterface]` as I initially expected.

This is a bit of a nuisance, as dealing with these builders now requires lots of `asInstanceOf` calls to recover the type.

Why does it happen, and (given that we can't change the library code) is there anything that we can do to work around the `asInstanceOf`s?

Comment: What is the type of `instanceOfLibInterface`?

Comment: could you show indeed the declaration of the `LibInterface` implementation classes (what is the highest in the chain?) and how you declared/instantiated the `instanceOfLibInterface`?

Comment: You may want o read about *f-bounded polymorphism*.